# How to change djangos default User Creation Form

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I extended the Django User Model and added a required `ForeignKeyField` called company. Now I also need to Change the default user creation Form. What I tried so far was:

Creating a new Form that Inherits from the default `UserCreationForm` form:

```
class MyUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    company = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Company.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = ('username', 'company')
```

Adding it to my extended Django Admin:

```
class ExtendedUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = MyUserCreationForm
    ...
admin.site.register(MyUser, ExtendedUserAdmin)
```

This does not work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you don't need to change `add_form`. All you need to do is add the following to `ExtendedUserAdmin`:

```
def __init__(self, model, admin_site):
    super().__init__(model, admin_site)
    self.add_fieldsets[0][1]['fields'] = ('username', 'password1', 'password2', 'company')
```